# How to output multiple pdf files from many data frame in a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, pdf, for-loop, output

I through `assign()` function to name many data frame.
Use this script:

```
> for (i in 1:15)
{
  assign(paste0('TagIDNum',i),filter(Ordf,Ordf$TagID==i))
}
```

Got this 15 data frame
[image]

Next step I need to output scatterplot of these 15 data frames with `pairs()` function and `for loop` to output pdf in once.
Here is my script:

```
 for (i in 1:15)
{

  pdf(paste('TagPlotNum',j,'.pdf',sep=''))
  x<-paste('TagIDNum',j,sep='')
  print(pairs(~x[,11]+x[,38]+x[,39]+x[,40]+x[,41]+x[,43]))
  dev.off()
}
```

But I got this error information
[image]

Error information: incorrect number of dimensions
And I found that the `x` had no data, just a `value` as follow:
[image]

I will do some analysis in next steps, so this problem disturb for 2 days.
Post this article to ask any expert to solve this issue.
In my opinion, maybe `paste()` function have something to think, but I don't know how to solve this topic.
Here is my R information:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: In your current code you have this line: `print(pairs(~x[,11]+x[,38]+x[,39]+x[,40]+x[,41]+x[,43]))`. Try replacing it with this:`pairs(eval(parse(text=x))[, c(11, 38, 39, 40, 41, 43)])`.

Comment: When you use paste you are making a string, not passing a variable, e.g. try just `j = 1` and `x<-paste('TagIDNum',j,sep='')`, so x is not a table.

Comment: It's a hack but use 'get'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your output, `x` is the string `"TagIDNum11"`, not the object with that name. You can get that however using `get()`, i.e.

```
x<-get(paste('TagIDNum',j,sep=''))
```

FYI, spaces are free, your code will be much more readable if you use them, i.e.

```
x <- get(paste('TagIDNum', j, sep=''))
```